# How to find hidden files of git repository in Terminal of VSCode on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, hidden-files

So, I am cloning the git repo to the folder, and I want to check if there is a hidden file in that folder such as .git. And I found a command that will show all the files in the folder: *ls -la*. But, I tried to write the *ls -la* command in the terminal of VSCode but it threw a mistake or smth. So, I wonder are there any other commands in the terminal to show hidden files on Windows?

Comment: Linux commands will obviously not work on Windows, save for a very few cases. Use `dir /a` instead, or even better, just look at the folder in Windows Explorer.

Comment: At least on Windows, `.git` folders are not marked in the filesystem as "hidden". Visual Studio Code knows that that folder is generally "noise" when working in a repo, so it does not show it. Otherwise, if you actually have a Git repository, you have a `.git` folder.